# Sonarqube Analyse source code located in a folder named ".utils"

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I am trying to analyse my .NET solution but i can't analyse files (cs files) located in a folder named ".Utils".
The sonar runner seems to skip folders whose name begins with "."

Sample :

```
- My solution
 - Project1
     - Context
         - Class1.cs
     - .Utils
         - Class2.cs
```

Currently, i am able to analyse Class1.cs, but not Class2.cs.
Is it possible to force analyse of this kind of folder ?.

It would be better if I rename it into "Utils", but we have a lot of projects in this case...

```
Configuration:
SonarQube 5.1
Sonar Runner 2.4
Visual Studio BootStrapper 1.2
C# plugin 4.0
```

Thank you